# SetRemoteGoto closes the actual pdf

Tags: c#, itext, acrobat

I have got a Chunk in my PDF file, that has a SetRemoteGoto, it forwards me to another PDF. When I open this PDF file, and click on this Chunk, the original PDF closes.

How can I prevent that? 
Is it a setting in Acrobat Reader or I have to modify my code?

Answer (score 1):

I have two answers, depending on the context.

**If you are talking about a viewer inside a browser,** there is very little you can do: you click a link, and the current document is replaced with the new document, because the PDF can't instruct the browser to open a new tab or a new window.

**If you are talking about a standalone PDF viewer,** you can create an action that opens a document in a new window. In that case, you don't use `SetRemoteGoto`, but `SetAction`:

```
 Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Link");
 PdfAction action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(filename, destination, false,  true);
 chunk.SetAction(action);
```

See [the API Docs](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAction.html#gotoRemotePage-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-) for the value of the parameters:

- `filename` - the path to the file
- `dest` - the destination name (a named destination in the target file)
- `isName` - if `true` sets the destination as a name, if `false` sets it as a string
- `newWindow` - open the document in a new window if `true`; if `false` the current document is replaced by the new document.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the PDFs are viewed.

If they are viewed within a browser, this is the standard behavior. You may be able to open a second viewer window with an accordingly formed link.

If they are viewed in Acrobat/Reader, it is an user setting: in the Documnents tab in the Preferences deactivate "Open cross document links in the same window". (unfortunately, this option is activated by factory defaults).